# How do I post a photo to instagram from the computer?

Tags: digital

I took a photo with my Nikon, edited in Gimp but I can't upload the .jpg to instagram from the computer. I get an error "Something went wrong. Please try again.".

I read square photos should be 1080x1080px, I reduced it to this but get the same error.

Does anyone upload photos to instagram they took with a digital camera or you can only upload from your phone? I asked on Quora a couple of months ago but didn't get any reply, not sure if it's something obvious.

It shows the preview when I upload but when I click next it gives the error.

Comment: Have you try to change the browser? I have no problem to upload it with Firefox/Windows

Comment: Nothing special in uploading from a computer, except that you are possibly using a different network...

Comment: Thank you, changing the browser ended up working.

Comment: More likely a problem of cookie than a problem of browser, though. There are web standards and even Edge follows them...

Comment: @xenoid, in some cases safari have challenge to follow them :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases the obvious action is to change the browser. The problem is different browsers support different versions of web "actions" and so on so Instagram may not support particular browsers/version. Also cleanup a browser cache, logout/login may help.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me before, too. It was caused by arithmetic coding that is enabled by default when storing JPEG files in GIMP. It's a more modern (or better - less ancient) algorithm used in JPEG compression, but some software doesn't support it.

To disable it, expand the "Advanced Options" in the Export dialog and uncheck "Use arithmetic coding".

[image: Disable arithmetic coding in GIMP]

Comment: I'm using GIMP 2.10.22 and the Use arithmetic coding is not ticked by default in this case.